# Run method with arguments from NSArray objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, methods, arguments, nsarray

I have a an array that contains all of the arguments for the method that I want to call. How can I run the method with arguments from an array.

Let's say my method is: `-(void)myFunction:(id)sender arg1:(id)arg1 arg2:(id)arg2`
and my array might have : `self, @"myfirst obj", somevar, nil`

I want to call `myFunction:arg1:arg2:` with the arguments from my array.
How can I accomplish this?

Also the array size can change because the methods change because I'm injecting code into an app so I can't rename the methods.

*Note: I can't change the method name*

*Also note that my array item's count and types change.*

Comment: do you want a variadic method? or just one of those args to be an array?

Comment: How can the array size change if you're calling the same method? It takes a specific number of arguments. Can you give an example of how'd you'd call this, and why `[self myFunction:array[0] arg1:array[1] arg2:array[2]]` doesn't work?

Comment: @Rob Napier that won't work because my method varies.

Comment: @Grady Player Neither. Re-read the question, I made some edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using `NSInvocation`

```
NSArray *arguments = @[self, @1, @2];

NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(myFunction:arg1:arg2:)]];
invocation.target = self;
invocation.selector = @selector(myFunction:arg1:arg2:);

[arguments enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [invocation setArgument:&obj atIndex:idx+2]; // You must add 2 to the index as the first 2 argument are reserved for the system 
}];

[invocation invoke];
```